# How can I avoid XCode resetting the location on my iPhone every time it runs

Tags: ios, xcode, geolocation, gps

Every time I run XCode, my location is being reset to a location in London. It doesn't recover until I reset my device.

How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 9):

This took me a month or two to spot and track down, so I am posting for the benefit of others.
as Apple Customer Support were unable to diagnose it, and even went so far as to swap my device for a new one- which of course didn't help. There was nothing about this on Google.

I eventually diagnosed it by setting "Find My Friends" to geofence my real location and send a message when it spotted me leave. The second I started running my app on Xcode it pinged instantly.

There is a setting in XCode that sets the GPS to a chosen dummy location whenever you run your app. It can be found by selecting Product>Scheme>Edit Scheme from the top menu, then select "Run appname" on the left and "Options" at the top. The one you want is "Core Location: Allow Location Simulation."

Just uncheck that box. Problem solved.

Comment: does this affect GPS Simulation on simulator?